# calculation based on input field for a result on the fly

Tags: javascript, input, calculated-field

This is an extension to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757355/javascript-calculator-as-users-type-numbers).

---

My situation:

- I need a user to enter a decimal value (ie 0.05) and show a simple calculation on the fly as the user types (or pastes). The example shown works for whole numbers but not when a decimal is entered into the input field.
- I need to display the result in multiple places. I assumed I could just update getElementById to getElementByClass but that didn't work.

My Code:

```
<input type="text" name="capname" id="numberField" value="0.07" maxlength="5" />
<span name="mpd" id="mpdresult" class="mpdresult" ></span>  
<span class="mpdresult" ></span> (second display)

<script>
window.onload = function() {
   var base = 500;
   var numberField = document.getElementById('numberField');
   numberField.onkeyup = numberField.onpaste = function() {
      if(this.value.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById('mpdresult').innerHTML = '';
         return;
      }
      var number = parseInt(this.value);
      if(isNaN(number)) return;
      document.getElementById('mpdresult').innerHTML = number * base;
   };
   numberField.onkeyup(); //could just as easily have been onpaste();
};
</script>
```

Comment: Most people here seem to have focused on the float parsing part of this. If you want to use `getElementsByClass` to update multiple inputs, you need to remember it returns an array instead of a single element. so you could get the array and then loop through the array setting each elements' innerHTML to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ChrisO'Kelly - i'll have to look into that some more. Maybe JQuery has a simpler option.

Comment: it does. with jQ you would use `$('.classname').each(function(){doSomethingWith(this)});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use 
 var number = parseFloat(this.value);

instead of 
var number = parseInt(this.value);

Answer (score 0):

use ParseFolat for Decimal Numbers

```
document.write(parseFloat("10.33") + "<br>");
```

[ParseFloatSample](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parsefloat)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. http://jsfiddle.net/janCY/
2. there is no such function `getElementByClass`. There is `getElementsByClassName`, it returns array with elements. But why don't use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll look up some JQuery stuff, but I'm not too familiar with it. Any hints on where to start? Would I replace the whole script or just the action of placing the returned value in multiple places?